# how to fix spelling mistakes in a database have multiple records in that records there are more records

Tags: sql

i have a database having country, city, state and hotels in these table country name has multiple identical records for eg mexico is wrongly spelled as maxico and mxico and mexico,other records like usa and united states of america and america these type of records are having mutiple same wrongly spelled states and states has multiple wrong spelled cities  but hotels are unique and i want them to set them to there right city and state and country for eg. some hotel is in chicago city Illinois state and country is usa. please help me how can i fix this

Comment: Long term you should add some validation in the client so that incorrect input is not possible otherwise you'll have to fix this over and over again.

Comment: i have fixed the problem by checking these table one by one because these tables are mapped by unique id to each other so i made a join query and delete unwanted one and replace right one to the original city, state and country as it was very time consuming but i got only this way to correct this

Answer (score 0):

This type of data problem is hard. There is no built-in simple way to determine the "right spelling". Many databases have one of two capabilities built in that can help -- either "soundex" algorithms or Levenshtein distance.

What should you do? If you really want to fix this problem, create a table with the misspelled name and the correct value that you want. *This table will need to be maintained manually, such as in a spreadsheet.* Then use this table when *importing* data and use only the rectified value.

Better yet, set up a reference table with only the correct names.  Create a second table with alternative names, which is maintained as above.

Answer (score 0):

you could do an update if you know all the different scenarios that are incorrect

```
  update tbl
  set city = 'Mexico'
  where city in ('maxico', 'mxico')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,you can list all values the country column has,and then check wether the values is right, if it is wrong, just use update clause to fix the wrong value, like below:

```
  update my_table set country = 'Mexico' where country in ('maco', 'xico');
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on infrastructure you're running.

If you have access to some ETL tools, they often have DataQuality capabilities, often with databases used in correcting adresses. Those are often paid.

If you are a "private" developer, then you might not want to use paid data, so you can look for open data sources, like [https://catalog.data.gov allegheny country addresses](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/allegheny-county-address-points-07dff_).

You can use multitude of algorithms and solutions, ranging from simple distances in word space to neural networks pre-trained to do just that.